# In LibreOffice Calc, can be a digit added directly after a regex match in single find/replace operation?

Tags: regex, libreoffice-calc

I want to add character `5` after certain pattern found in the column (e.g. 4 digits).

Example:   `aa1234bb` → `aa12345bb`

Method:

**Find:** `([0-9]{4})`  with [**Regular Expressions** option checked](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions)

**Replace:** `$15`   - of course, this won't work, but workaround as `$1\u0035` does not work, too, it creates `1234\u0035`.

The workaround can be made using additional step, i.e. **Find:** `\u0035`, no regex, **Replace:** `5`. But can be the replacement made without this workaround which adds one step?

Comment: Works for me, `v6.0.3.2 x64`

Comment: This works for me as well.
I'm using Libreoffice 5.1.6.2.

Comment: Does not work for me in Calc 6.0.4.2 on Win 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$15` doesn't work in your version, then `&5` works for a single group reference.